# Using Git and Xcode, how to branch off or create a new project from all existing code?

Tags: xcode, git

This question explores the coding practice with Xcode and together with Git.

If we create a project called "Simple", and now everything works, and we'd like to keep this as it is, possibly add to the Apps store.  But at the same time, we would like to create a new project, using all source code, `.h`, `.c`, `.xib`, and all image files.  How would we do that?  (maybe there are different ways to do it).

But ideally, there would be a folder called "Simple", with all the files as they are, and then up the parent folder, there is a new folder called "Complex", and the `Simple.xcodeproj` should no longer be that name, but should be `Complex.xcodeproj`, and so is the folder at the same level of `Complex.xcodeproj`, that folder also should not be `Simple` but `Complex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to fork `Simple`, just use git clone and rename it:

```
git clone Simple Complex
cd Complex
mv Simple.xcodeproj Complex.xcodeproj
```

then open `Complex.xcodeproj`, fix what need to be fixed and commit.

Hopefully you used only relative paths in your Xcode project so their won't be too many manual adjustments to do.

Comment: inside of the `Complex` folder, there is yet another folder called `Simple`... and should be renamed `Complex` as well...  but I just don't know if the `.xcodeproj` will be confused if it was looking for a path called `Simple` somewhere

Comment: Yes you should rename it and fix the Xcode project accordingly. That's what I meant by *fix what need to be fixed*.

Comment: What do you mean "fix the Xcode project accordingly"?  That can be kind of broad...  I found that we can rename the project by clicking on the project name in the navigation panel... but can't rename the folder name of the project...

Comment: In Xcode, if a file is not found, its name appears in red. If you rename the folder `Simple` to `Complex`, Xcode will no longer find the files inside. In Xcode you have to find those files (in red) and change their path to point to the new location (or remove them and re-import them if it is easier).

Comment: Now that I know more about branching in Git and the App submission process, seems like we can just `git co -b complex` and work on it... and we can create a simple branch by `git co -b simple master` (creating simple based off master), and now we can say `git co simple` and `git co complex` and go to each project, and submission to the App store is ok in this same folder anyway (`git co` is an alias I have for `git checkout`).